"You must install or update .NET to run this application" error specifying a minor version when trying to run a Windows Service
I have a Windows Service application that targets .NET 6 (Windows).
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Platforms>x64</Platforms>
  </PropertyGroup>

For some reason, one of our customers (Windows 11) encountered an error when trying to run this service.
Screenshot of an error in Event Viewer
My question is: Why is the system complaining about a specific version of the .NET runtime, particularly focusing on the minor version?
Here’s how my *.runtimeconfig.json looks:
{
  "runtimeOptions": {
    "tfm": "net6.0",
    "frameworks": [
      {
        "name": "Microsoft.NETCore.App",
        "version": "6.0.0"
      },
      {
        "name": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.App",
        "version": "6.0.0"
      }
    ],
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true,
      "System.Reflection.Metadata.MetadataUpdater.IsSupported": false,
      "System.Runtime.Serialization.EnableUnsafeBinaryFormatterSerialization": false
    }
  }
}

I've tried to reproduce this case on Windows 10, and the Windows Service was installed successfully with only version 6.0.32 of the .NET runtime installed.
